# I am inserting values in the array, then I am displaying that value to the textarea, in this array I need to remove duplication names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this SkillIds array if i found duplication name then i need to remove that names..

```
var SkillIds = [];

$('#SkillSets table tr :checked').each(function () {
  SkillIds.push($(this).data("id"));
});

$('#textarea').val(SkillIds.tostring());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [$.unique()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

> Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed.

```
$('#textarea').val($.unique(SkillIds).tostring());
```

---

Or you can use [$.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
$('#SkillSets table tr :checked').each(function () {
    var data = $(this).data("id");
    if ($.inArray(data, SkillIds) === -1) {
        SkillIds.push(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var SkillIds = [];

$('#SkillSets table tr :checked').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    if( SkillIds.indexOf(id) == -1 ){//if element is not in array
        SkillIds.push(id);
    }
});

$('#textarea').val(SkillIds.toString());//typo here tostring() should be toString()
```